# Using ranges in input attributes with ng-daterangepicker in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to implement the ng-daterangepicker to my app.

So far it's working, but when I try to add the `ranges` attribute, it gives me `Error: [$parse:lexerr]` in the console.

This is the code so far:

```
<input type='daterange' 
       placeholder="Date range" 
       class="form-control"
       format="DD/MM/YYYY" 
       ng-model="search.date" 
       ranges="{
              'Yesterday': {'startDate': 'moment().subtract(1, "days")', 'endDate': 'moment().subtract(1, "days")'}
               }"
/>
```

Am I messing up with the syntax?

Comment: The first double quote in `moment().subtract(1, "days")` is closing the attribute. Do you have to escape the double quotes?

Comment: Also bad practice to have logic in your views, why don't you move the moment() statements to the controller?

Comment: Thought the same, but in the example he does it like this... https://github.com/luisfarzati/ng-bs-daterangepicker